# setting up sendmail on debian?

Tags: debian, php, sendmail, exim

I have a LAMP localhost server setup for some development and I want to test out if my code is working.  Some of the tests involve checking if the correct emails are sent out by the code at the correct time.

For this, my code needs to be able to send emails.  It does not need to receive emails back.

I have LAMP running on Debian.  How do I setup setup sending emails on Debian?  Apparently it already has something called exim instead of sendmail?

Comment: So you really want an outgoing MTA which can accept a mail message locally and deliver it; not necessarily *sendmail* specifically?

Answer (score 1):

Exim provides "real sendmail" look alike program called sendmail. The look alike supports most common options used when sending using "real sendmail".

**So**: Your PHP code may send via "sendmail" program (default on unix).

Most likely you Exim autoconfigured itself. You may send a test message to verify it. Use the command below for test (use valid recipient email):

```
(echo Subject: test; echo) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -v -i jd@example.net
```

Comment: The default config only allows send mail locally.

Comment: AFAIK It is not default in many (linux) distributions. Which distribution do you use?

Comment: It's the default in Debian, which is what the OP is using.